# Apply specific catalog price rule to price

Tags: magento-enterprise, discount, catalog-price-rules

I have the raw product price in a variable and i want to be able to apply only a specific rule to it.

Right now what i am doing is iterating over all the rules, conditioning only the ones i want. What i have today (i simplified the code here):

```
$productPrice = $product->getPrice();
$catRul = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogrule/rule')-getRulesFromProduct(Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d'), $websiteId, $userGroupId, $data['entity_id']);
if(isset($catRul) && !empty($catRul)) {
    foreach($catRul as $rule) {
        $catalogRulObj = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load($rule['rule_id']);
        $ruleData = $catalogRulObj->getData();
        if($ruleData['is_active'] === '1'){ // Here i am conditioning with a couple more stuff
              // Here i want to apply this rule conditioned in $ruleData; only, not all like below \/
              $productPrice = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->calcProductPriceRule($product, $product->getPrice());
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case, if anyone bump on this same question in the future, i managed to solve this using something like this:

```
$productPrice = $product->getPrice();
$catRul = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogrule/rule')-getRulesFromProduct(Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d'), $websiteId, $userGroupId, $data['entity_id']);
if(isset($catRul) && !empty($catRul)) {
    foreach($catRul as $rule) {
        $catalogRulObj = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load($rule['rule_id']);
        $ruleData = $catalogRulObj->getData();
        if($ruleData['is_active'] === '1'){ // Here i am conditioning with a couple more stuff
              $productPrice = Mage::helper('catalogrule')->calcPriceRule($ruleData['simple_action'], $ruleData['discount_amount'], $productPrice);
        }
    }
}
```